# Anonymous group video calls

Tags: video, phone, communication, anonymization

I'd like to have a work meeting where all members are anonymous.

Using Zoom and forcing all participants to download third-party software (such as video filters and voice changers) is not an option due to difficulty of setup. However, if it's something that can be easily installed that would work fine.

Instead, I'm imagining a website where I can create a room and share a link, that functions exactly like Zoom but anonymizes people's voices, faces, and names.

It doesn't have to be cryptographically secure, and nothing illegal will happen, so actual *security* is not a big factor at all.

Does something like this exist?

Comment: Apparently Microsoft Teams has an [anonymous feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/anonymous-users-in-meetings).